# Checking the environment variable without using GetLastError() == ERROR_ENVVAR_NOT_FOUND in VC++

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, environment-variables, getlasterror

Here is my code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<Windows.h>
using namespace std;
#define BUFSIZE 4602
#define VARNAME TEXT("zzz")
int main()
{

    TCHAR chNewEnv[BUFSIZE];
    GetEnvironmentVariable(VARNAME, chNewEnv, BUFSIZE);
    if(GetLastError()==ERROR_ENVVAR_NOT_FOUND)
    {
        cout<<"Hello";
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"Bye";
    }
return 0;
}
```

I am checking whether zzz environment variable is available or not. I need to do the same without using `if(GetLastError()==ERROR_ENVVAR_NOT_FOUND)`. Is there any way?

I am doing the same program using C# in which I don't use `GetLastError()`. I need to make these two programs similar that is why I am asking without the use  of `GetLastError()`. Here is  my C# snippet

```
string abc =Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("zzz"); 
if (abc == null || abc.ToUpper() == "NULL" || abc.ToUpper() == "NUL")
```

Comment: Why do you need to do it without GetLastError?

Comment: I need it to check if someone set the variable value as "NULL" or "null"

Comment: Okay. So why do you need to do that without using GetLastError?

Comment: No if the value is given as null it will GetLastError wont return ERROR_ENVVAR_NOT_FOUND rite? Since the environment variable is there with a value

Comment: @user3275057 Did you read my answer?

Comment: @manuell I am asking if the value is set as "null" not left empty

Comment: @manuell see this image http://i.stack.imgur.com/twTto.png

Comment: @user3275057 what do you mean? "null" as string of 4 characters?

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. Where does the image come from? what does it mean to have "null" here? What GetEnvironmentVariable is telling you?

Comment: GetEnvironmentVariable, as the name implies, gets the environment variable. So if there is a value, you can check the value to see if it is null. There is no special function to tell you if is null.

Comment: @manuell Sorry I edited the question to make it clear

Comment: @Gerald I have the same functionality in a C# program where I dont use `GetLastError()`. I need to make these two programs look alike thats why I am asking to do without using `GetLastError`

Comment: Then you will need to write a function that mimics the .NET method Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable. In that function you will need to use GetLastError, because that is just how it has to be done in C++. Trying to write C++ code that matches C# code is going to be difficult unless you plan on writing a ton of wrappers.

Comment: @user3275057 what is the `BUFSIZE==0` in your code? Is it for real?

Comment: @user3275057 Please clarify, again. What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: @manuell sorry it is a typo I edited

Comment: @manuell not working in the sense the GetEnvironment is returning a non zero value

Comment: @user3275057 Yes. Building with MBCS, the return value is 4, as "null" is a 4 bytes string. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: @manuell yes I know that  but I am asking any way to find without using `GetLastError`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50007/discussion-between-manuell-and-user3275057)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `GetLastError`, as you may encounter cases where a variable is defined with no value.

Such cases can be emulated with:

```
SetEnvironmentVariable( "foo", "" );
```

When `GetEnvironmentVariable` return 0, it may be that the variable doesn't exist, or that is exists with an empty content. In the later case, `GetLastError` returns 0.

If you don't care (that is: a nonexistent variable or an empty one is the same for you), then don't bother with `GetLastError`.

---

Side note. You should always make a first call with a NULL nSize argument, as the documentation states:

> If lpBuffer is not large enough to hold the data, the return value is
>   the buffer size, in characters, required to hold the string and its
>   terminating null character and the contents of lpBuffer are undefined.

And, I just tested (Windows 7), in such case `GetLastError` returns 0 (awkward, if you ask me)

---

[image: setting a variable in 7]

Edit: On Windows 7, when I set an user variable to "null", the value retrieved by `GetEnvironmentVariable` (MBCS) is a 5 bytes string 'n', 'u', 'l', 'l', '\0'

---

Code (UNICODE build):

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>


#define BUFSIZE 4602
#define VARNAME L"zzz"

const wchar_t * MyGetEnv( const wchar_t * pszVarName, wchar_t * pszVarValue,
                          size_t cbValue ) {

    DWORD dwCopied = GetEnvironmentVariable( pszVarName, pszVarValue, cbValue );
    // The line bellow MAY BE COMMENTED OUT IF YOU REALLY
    // DON'T LIKE GETLASTERROR, AS cbCopied WILL BE ZERO FOR
    // NON-EXISTENT VARIABLE
    if ( GetLastError() != NO_ERROR ) return NULL; // doesn't exist, or error
    if ( dwCopied == 0 ) return NULL; // var is empty
    return pszVarValue;

}

int main() {

    wchar_t szVarValue[ BUFSIZE ];
    const wchar_t * pszVarValue = MyGetEnv( VARNAME, szVarValue,
                                            _countof( szVarValue ) );
    if ( pszVarValue == NULL ) {
        printf( "No variable or empty value\n" );
    } else if ( ( _wcsicmp( pszVarValue, L"null" ) == 0 ) ||
                ( _wcsicmp( pszVarValue, L"nul" )  == 0 )    ) {
        printf( "Special 'null' or 'nul' value\n" );
    } else {
        wprintf( L"Value is %s\n", szVarValue );
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by environment variable exists with an empty content. I cant create an environment with an empty content (I cant click "OK" in the window). When I created a variable with the value of single space (" ") or "null" `GetEnvironmentVariable` is not returning zero

Comment: Reread my answer please. Using `SetEnvironmentVariable( "foo", "" );` allows you to define an environment variable with an empty content. **Both** `GetEnvironmentVariable` and `GetLastError` will return 0.

Comment: No I dont want to set environment variable via `SetEnvironmentVariable( "foo", "" )` I need to set through `MyComputer>Properties>EnvironmentVariable`

Comment: Why do you say "No"??? It was just an example! An executable **may** see a variable as defined but empty.

Comment: Sorry but SetEnvironmentVariable( "foo", "" ); will set a particular environment I dont need to set a new environment I need to find the environment which is set as null. You said in the answer that it is taking "null" as 5 bytes so any other way to find?

Comment: @manuell Actually, `GetLastError` returns the last value set (could be anything) if the variable is empty. However, if you call `SetLastError(0)` before calling `GetEnvironmentVariable`, `GetLastError` will of course return `0`.

Comment: @johv When the documentation for an API explicitly states that you have to use `GetLastError` to distinguish certain conditions, then you do NOT have to call `SetLastError(0)` before calling the API.

Comment: Go ahead and try it. E.g. call `SetLastError(42)` first, and try to get an empty variable. `GetLastError()` returns `42`. Or try to get a non-existing variable, and then get an empty one, and call `GetLastError()`. The documentation rather uselessly only mentions what happens to `GetLastError()` if the specified environment variable is not found, and nothing about what happens on success.

Comment: @johv o_O You are right, so I am wrong. Today I learned something, thank you! (and I see that as a BUG in the `GetEnvironmentVariable` implementation, or a BUG in the `GetEnvironmentVariable` documentation)